# TCL/TK error message doesn't help. Can some help me, please

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am new to TK and I think the error message that I am getting is with TK.  Here is the error message:

> `unknown option "-state"; must be one of -background, -bd, -bg, -borderwidth, -columnbd, -columnborderwidth, -columnrelief, -cursor, -exportselection, -fg, -fillcolumn, -font, -foreground, -height, -highlightbackground, -highlightcolor, -highlightthickness, -labelanchor, -labelbackground, -labelbd, -labelbg, -labelborderwidth, -labelfg, -labelfont, -labelforeground, -labelheight, -labelimage, -labelrelief, -labels, -relief, -resizablecolumns, -selectbackground, -selectborderwidth, -selectcommand, -selectforeground, -selectmode, -setgrid, -takefocus, -width, -xscrollcommand or -yscrollcommand`

errorInfo trace:

```
unknown option "-state"; must be one of -background, -bd, -bg, -borderwidth, -columnbd, -columnborderwidth, -columnrelief, -cursor, -exportselection, -fg, -fillcolumn, -font, -foreground, -height, -highlightbackground, -highlightcolor, -highlightthickness, -labelanchor, -labelbackground, -labelbd, -labelbg, -labelborderwidth, -labelfg, -labelfont, -labelforeground, -labelheight, -labelimage, -labelrelief, -labels, -relief, -resizablecolumns, -selectbackground, -selectborderwidth, -selectcommand, -selectforeground, -selectmode, -setgrid, -takefocus, -width, -xscrollcommand or -yscrollcommand
    while executing
"::mclistbox::Canonize $w option [lindex $args 0]"
    (procedure "::mclistbox::WidgetProc" line 211)
    invoked from within
"::mclistbox::WidgetProc .autoQuote.reportInfoTab.f.tit76.f.mcl84 cget -state"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval ::mclistbox::WidgetProc {.autoQuote.reportInfoTab.f.tit76.f.mcl84} $command $args"
    (procedure ".autoQuote.reportInfoTab.f.tit76.f.mcl84" line 1)
    invoked from within
"$w cget -state"
    (procedure "tk::ListboxBeginSelect" line 18)
    invoked from within
"tk::ListboxBeginSelect [::mclistbox::convert .autoQuote.reportInfoTab.f.tit76.f.mcl84.framecol1.listbox -W] [[::mclistbox::convert .autoQuote.reportIn..."
    invoked from within
"if {[winfo exists [::mclistbox::convert .autoQuote.reportInfoTab.f.tit76.f.mcl84.framecol1.listbox -W]]} {
    tk::ListboxBeginSelect [::mclistbox::conve..."
    (command bound to event)
```

This isn't my code but it looks like it's going the Widget library.  I have found the routine 'widgetProc' and it appears to have a '-state' switch.  I am just drawing a blank right now.

Here is my environment:

- Windows 7 Enterprise SP1.
- tcl version: 8.5.11.1
- bwidgets 1.95
- iwidgets 4.0.1
- tcllib 1.14

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't caused by **widgetProc**, but rather by **::mclistbox::Canonize**. Now unfortunately, I'm not familiar with it but a quick Google search shows [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-gui/2009-February/000909.html) result with similar lack of resolution. However, the dates on the posting would lead me to make an optimistic suggestion that you upgrade to a more recent version if possible. If that is not possible, maybe you could show us the code you're using - it maybe possible that the way you're calling it is triggering the error.

Comment: Source to mclistbox is at http://tcllib.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tcllib/mclistbox/mclistbox.tcl?revision=1.34&view=markup

Comment: Also, as far as I can see there should be a `-state` option. Hmm.

Comment: @DonalFellows Thanks! Looks like the OP hasn't returned, so the mystery will continue a little longer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick workaround. Not sure if it's entirely correct or not, but it worked for me.
Add the following under line 77 ( which should be "array set widgetOptions [list \" )

```
-state       {State           State} \
```

Would provide a diff, but it's such a simple fix I don't feel that it warrants it.